# when running npm install --legacy-peer-deps, got error: Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: Unknown

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am trying to run
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

but got some error.

here is the error:

```
Error: Error on worker #1: Error: Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: Unknown.     
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (portal/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113076:22)
```

Also I added a log on this line
typescript.js:113076:22

```
            console.log(node, node.kind)

            ts.Debug.fail("Unhandled SyntaxKind: ".concat(ts.Debug.formatSyntaxKind(node.kind), "."));
```

the output is

```
t undefined
```

I think it might be a node version issue, but not sure what is happening, if anyone can help, I am very appreciated.
Let me know if anymore infomation need to be provided.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this issue today too. I found that targeting Typescript < 4.8 was the key to resolving this issue.

In your package.json change your typescript version (dev dependency) to something akin to this:
`"typescript": "<4.8"`
or specifically set the version eg
`"typescript": "4.6.4"`

You should check the node_modules folder to ensure that you did not install the 4.8.2 package which I think has this incompatability.

Comment: this change fixed it

Comment: version 4.8.4 still has this issue, no idea where it comes from though

Comment: this worked for me on Angular 11 ... "typescript": "~4.1.6"

Comment: thanks so much for your help on this one!